# Testar se uma chave contém um valor dentro de um json

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando verificar se em determinada chave de um json existe um valor, mas não estou conseguindo. Já tentei utilizar includes, indexOf, some, dentre outras funções javascript.

Tenho um array com os meses:

```
const MONTHS = ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Maio', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'];
```

De uma consulta de um banco de dados tenho o resultado de uma query que soma registros de uma coluna da tabela e os agrupa em meses. Basicamente o json retornado tem a seguinte estrutura:

**params**

```
{
    "open": {
        "mes": "Abr",
        "total": "56.00"
    },
    "pay": null,
    "cancel": null
}
```

Na estrutura acima foi retornado apenas o mês de Abr, no entanto, se tivesse mais registros e esses registros contivessem os demais meses eles seriam retornados também. Então, em determinado momento pode ser que eu tenha 7 meses com dados e outros 5 sem dados, por exemplo.
No javascript estou tentando popular os respectivos arrays para incluí-los em um gráfico:

```
var data_open = [];
var data_pay = [];
var data_cancel = [];

$.each(params, function(key_param, value_param) {
        if (key_param == 'open') {
            $.each(MONTHS, function(key_open, value_open){
                if (MONTHS.indexOf(value_param.mes) > -1 && value_open == value_param.mes) {
                    data_open.push(value_param.total);
                } else {
                    data_open.push(0);
                }
            });
        } else if (key_param == 'pay') {
            $.each(MONTHS, function(key_pay, value_pay){                
                if (MONTHS.indexOf(value_param.mes) > -1 && value_pay == value_param.mes) {
                    data_pay.push(value_param.total)
                  } else {
                    data_pay.push(0);
                  }
            });
        } else if (key_param == 'cancel') {
            $.each(MONTHS, function(key_cancel, value_cancel){                
                if (MONTHS.indexOf(value_param.mes) > -1 && value_cancel == value_param.mes) {
                    data_cancel.push(value_param.total);
                  } else {
                    data_cancel.push(0);
                  }
            });
        }
    });
```

A questão é que quando a chave do json tem as chaves **mes** e **total** o algoritmo consegue popular o array dentro do if, por exemplo a chave **open** do json possui registros, mas as chaves **pay** e **cancel** não, e nesses que não tem registros o algoritmo não consegue continuar a execução.

Como posso fazer para verificar se as chaves possuem registro, e incluir a lógica para continuar a execução e popular os arrays com os valores 0.00?

**RESOLUÇÃO**

```js
const MONTHS = ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Maio', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'];

const json_data = {
    "open": {
        "mes": "Abr",
        "total": "56.00"
    },
    "pay": null,
    "cancel": null
}

var data_open = [];
var data_pay = [];
var data_cancel = [];

$.each(json_data, function(key_param, value_param) {
        if (key_param == 'open') {
            $.each(MONTHS, function(key_open, value_open){
                if (value_param && value_param.hasOwnProperty('mes') && MONTHS.indexOf(value_param.mes) > -1 && value_open == value_param.mes) {
                    data_open.push(value_param.total);
                } else {
                    data_open.push(0);
                }
            });
        }else if (key_param == 'pay') {
            $.each(MONTHS, function(key_pay, value_pay){                
                if (value_param && value_param.hasOwnProperty('mes') && MONTHS.indexOf(value_param.mes) > -1 && value_pay == value_param.mes) {
                    data_pay.push(value_param.total)
                  } else {
                    data_pay.push(0);
                  }
            });
        }else if (key_param == 'cancel') {
            $.each(MONTHS, function(key_cancel, value_cancel){                
                if (value_param && value_param.hasOwnProperty('mes') && MONTHS.indexOf(value_param.mes) > -1 && value_cancel == value_param.mes) {
                    data_cancel.push(value_param.total);
                  } else {
                    data_cancel.push(0);
                  }
            });
        }
    });
    
    $.each(data_open, function(key, value){
       document.getElementById('result_open').innerHTML += '<p>' + key + " - " + value + '</p>';
    });
    
    $.each(data_pay, function(key, value){
       document.getElementById('result_pay').innerHTML += '<p>' + key + " - " + value + '</p>';
    });
    
    $.each(data_cancel, function(key, value){
       document.getElementById('result_cancel').innerHTML += '<p>' + key + " - " + value + '</p>';
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>ORDENS ABERTAS</p>
<div id="result_open"></div>
<p>ORDENS PAGAS<p>
<div id="result_pay"></div>
<p>ORDENS CANCELADAS</p>
<div id="result_cancel"></div>
```

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer. Talvez seja sensato adicionar um exemplo do que você quer como _entrada_ no seu script e o que você quer como _saída_. :)

Comment: Eu quero popular os arrays "data_open", "data_pay" e "data_cancel" com os dados que estão no json. Só que quando uma chave do json está vazia/nula o algoritmo não consegue processar o código, creio que é porque nos ifs a verificação das chaves não está correta. No exemplo que postei, a chave "open" do json contém dados e nesse caso o algoritmo processa a verificação e continua com o código, mas nas chaves em que não há dados, como a chave "pay" e "cancel", isso não acontece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi bem sua dúvida, você deseja verificar se um objeto possui uma determinada propriedade, e precisa disso pois ocorre um erro em seu código no trecho `MONTHS.indexOf(value_param.mes)` dentro do `if` "pay" e "cancel" por conta destes itens serem nulos em seu json.

Para corrigir o problema primeiramente você deve verificar se `value_param` é diferente de `null`, em seguida você pode usar a função [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) para verificar se o seu objeto possui a propriedade em questão. Seu código final ficara semelhante ao seguinte:

```
if (value_param && value_param.hasOwnProperty('mes') && MONTHS.indexOf(value_param.mes) > -1 && value_pay == value_param.mes) {
   // seu código
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, agora executou corretamente!